# @font-face - Custom font not displayed after importing .ttf and .svg

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

On a website that I'm developing I am able to import and display via `@font-face`  my custom font.

It works perfectly on different browsers

In the specific what I did was:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MyCustomFont';
src: url('assets/fonts/MyCustomFont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('assets/fonts/MyCustomFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'); /* IE6-IE8 */
src: url('assets/fonts/MyCustomFont.woff') format('woff'); /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
}

body {
font-family: 'MyCustomFont', sans-serif;
}
```

The problem is that when I try to import the **.ttf** and **.svg** formats the font is not displayed anymore and the Fallback font will be applied.

This is how I imported .svg and .ttf

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MyCustomFont';
src: url('assets/fonts/MyCustomFont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('assets/fonts/MyCustomFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'); /* IE6-IE8 */
src: url('assets/fonts/MyCustomFont.woff') format('woff'); /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
src: url('assets/fonts/MyCustomFont.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
src: url('assets/fonts/MyCustomFont.svg#svgMyCustomFont') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}

body {
font-family: 'MyCustomFont', sans-serif;
}
```

How come is this happening?

Is possible to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens when you put commas in between the url and the format.  Like this:  url('assets/fonts/MyCustomFont.woff'), format('woff');

Comment: @trav Same problem. Anyway in console I have no errors...

Answer (score 0):

Put a comma at the end of each line instead of a ";"  and only define the source once.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MyCustomFont';
src: url('assets/fonts/MyCustomFont.eot'), /* IE9 Compat Modes */
url('assets/fonts/MyCustomFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
url('assets/fonts/MyCustomFont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
url('assets/fonts/MyCustomFont.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
url('assets/fonts/MyCustomFont.svg#svgMyCustomFont') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Comment: Hi trav. 
Still nothing.

If I write it like you said I have the same problem